# Ubuntu 13.10 big problem with privilegies

Tags: ubuntu, chrome-os, chrome-book

I have HP 14 chromebook (with haswell celeron processor and 4 Gb of RAM, 4G), all is okay when I installed Ubuntu 13.10 saucy with crouton script I didn't get any errors.

But when I'm trying to install something, it says that I don't have privileges, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing from the command line, ensure you currently have root privileges. You can do this by typing `sudo apt-get install application`, which will then prompt you for the root/administrator password.

Comment: im installing with software center